# Посредник отрабатывается несколько раз

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Написал посредника в Laravel, который вызывается в большинстве страниц:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->session()->missing('inspected_arr'))
        {
            $insp_arr = collect([]);
            $request->session()->put('inspected_arr', $insp_arr);
        }
        if ($request->session()->has('web_id_tovar'))
        {
            $inspected_array = $request->session()->get('inspected_arr');
            $web_id_tovar = $request->session()->get('web_id_tovar');
            $inspected_array->push(2);
            $inspected_array = $inspected_array->unique();
            /*if ($inspected_array->has(4))
            {
                $inspected_array->pop();
            }*/
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

При простом переходе на другую страницу, он у меня отрабатывает аж 4 раза[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он отрабатывает несколько раз, как можно это отследить и исправить?

Comment: он срабатывает на каждом переходе где вызывается. Не совсем ясна суть задачи. Ещё отсутствует запись в сессию, где должна быть

Comment: @ArchDemon, мне нужно чтобы он отрабатывал только один раз, значение web_id_tovar кладется в сессию каждый раз, когда переходим на страницу с товаром

Comment: Сделайте отладку или логирование и проверьте откуда, и при каких переходах идут вызовы.